# Custom token sent to wallet , does not show in wallet

Tags: tokens, rinkeby

I am using the rinkeby test network and i created a custom token using the basic code stub given on the ethereum.org site. So I transferred to another account which is also on the rinkeby network. But the balance is not reflected. Can anybody help ?

Comment: Customs tokens have to be added to the wallet. Which wallet are you talking about? Also the code must be ERC20 or other token standards.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways to do this.

1. [Etherscan](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token-search). Enter the address of smart-contract where the token is deployed. Go to "Token holders" ([it will look like this](https://etherscan.io/token/Indorse#balances)).
2. You can check the balance by calling script below via loadScript() in your geth or geth console ([example](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console#non-interactive-use-jsre-script-mode)).

   ```
   var contractAddress = '0x';
   var abi = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"from","type":"address"},{"name":"to","type":"address"},{"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"who","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"to","type":"address"},{"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"name":"extraData","type":"bytes"}],"name":"approveAndCall","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"name":"spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}];
   var token = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(contractAddress);

   function getBalance(addr) {
   token.balanceOf.call(addr, function (err, bal) {
       if (err) { console.error(err) }
       console.log('token balance for account ' + addr + ' is ' + bal.toString(10));
   })
   }
   ```